# Multiplicative group mod $p^k$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

How does this group (where $p$ is an odd prime and $k$ is a positive integer) relate to multiplicative group of non-zero elements of $GF(p^k)$? I know that, when $k=1$, these are isomorphic, but I cannot figure out (or even find) the exact connection when $k>1$.

Comment: For $k>1$, both are cyclic. However, they have different number of elements: $p^k - 1$ in $GF(p^k)^*$ and $\varphi(p^k) = p^{k-1}(p-1)$ in $\mathbb Z^*_{p^k}$.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what puzzles me, since being cyclic is usually proved for the former, and then implied for that latter, but I don't understand how.

Comment: Can you give a link to the implication you mention? I believe the 'standard proofs' are to use roots of a polynomial for $GF(p^k)$ and to use a simple version of Hensel's Lemma for the multiplicative group mod $p^k$.

Comment: @S. Dolan Not knowing much about abstract algebra, I was misled by a remark I read on this site into believing in such an incorrect connection. Now I can see from all your comments that, except for $k=1$, these groups have nothing in common. The only reason not to delete my dumb question is to preserve the two intelligent and valuable answers below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two groups, $\Bbb{F}_{p^k}^\times$ and $\Bbb{Z}/(p^k)^\times$ are very different.

- First $\Bbb{F}_p$ is a field thus $x^d-1\in \Bbb{F}_p[x]$ has at most $d$-roots. This proves that $x^{p-1}-1$ is the smallest degree polynomial having every element of $\Bbb{F}_p^\times$ is its roots thus $\Bbb{F}_p^\times$ is cyclic with $p-1$-elements.
- The exact same argument shows that $\Bbb{F}_{p^k}^\times$ is cyclic with $p^k-1$-elements.

> What is $\Bbb{F}_{p^k}$ ? It is the splitting field of $x^{p^k}-x\in \Bbb{F}_{p}[x]$, it is the quotient ring $\Bbb{F}_{p}[x]/(f)$ for any $f\in \Bbb{F}_p[x]$ irreducible of degree $k$.

- For $p\ne 2$ then the binomial theorem gives $$(1+p)^{p^m}\equiv 1+p^{m+1}\bmod p^{m+2}$$
  this proves that $1+p\in \Bbb{Z}/(p^k)^\times$ has order $p^{k-1}$. Let $g\in \Bbb{Z}/(p^k)^\times$ such that its reduction $g\in \Bbb{F}_p^\times$ has order $p-1$. Then $g\in \Bbb{Z}/(p^k)^\times$ has order $(p-1)p^{r}$, if $r<k-1$ then $g (1+p)$ has order $(p-1)p^{k-1}$.

> Thus $\Bbb{Z}/(p^k)^\times$ is cyclic with $(p-1)p^{k-1}$ elements.

Answer (score 3):

You are dealing with two different structures :

1) The quotient $\mathbf Z/p^k$ is a *finite ring* w.r.t. to the addition and multiplication mod $p^k$. Note that this ring is a field iff $k=1$; for $k\ge 2$, it has divisors of zero.  The multiplicative invertible elements form naturally a group $(\mathbf Z/p^k)^*$ of order $\phi (p^k)=(p-1)p^{k-1}$, which is cyclic except when   $p=2, k\ge 2$, in which case it is of type $(2, 2^{k-2})$.

2) By definition, $GF(p^k)$ is the unique (up to isomorphism) *finite field* with $p^k$ elements. Note that the structural properties of finite fields are entirely known from Galois theory. A classical lemma asserts that any finite subgroup of the multiplicative group of a field is cyclic, so $GF(p^k)^*$ is cyclic of order $p^k-1$.

Summarizing, except for $k=1$, $(\mathbf Z/p^k)^*$ and $GF(p^k)^*$ do not play in the same league.